# Disable vibration of the phone, but leave it on smartwatch

Tags: notifications, 5.1-lollipop, vibration, docking-station, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to figure out the best setting for my Android 5.1 phone during my working hours.

When I'm at my workplace, my phone is constantly docked and in set to the Priority mode (this is automatic). When someone calls me, I get notification on the smartwatch. I set up Hangouts to vibration only and let it notify me in Priority mode (it is in the exceptions list).

I don't like the vibration of the docked phone, which may distract my colleagues, especially given the fact, that the only vibration I need is one of my smartwatch. At the same time I believe the smartwatch notifications are duplicates of phone notifications and if the latter are disabled, the former get disabled too.

Is there a possibility to disable docked phone vibration notification, while left smartwatch notifications intact? Any other suggestion to set up the phone in a workplace-friendly manner?

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear -> Settings [image: Settings icon] -> Mute phone alerts & calls

Comment: I don't want notifications on the phone to be disabled all the time. I just want them to be disabled only when the phone is docked.